# How to ask a "non-duplicate", with examples and info, without it being closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Some people take the time to ask a question fully. *Really* fully. They include examples, all info required and often link to other SO posts with comments like *"not a duplicate of this one because x y z"*. Soon enough, someone comes along and marks the post as a duplicate of the very link the OP explained wasn't the same.

I realise some people might say *"not a duplicate because my values are different"* or some lame excuse. I'm not on about them, long may they be policed and rightly so. I'm on about the other SO users who have a quirky or unusual problem that hasn't been answered before and they've laboured in vain, trawling the internet looking for an answer.

Comment: Presumably by *"some people"* you mean you and by *"a question"* you mean https://stackoverflow.com/q/59987512/3001761?

Comment: The usual: edit the question to explain why and how the duplicate does not apply to your question, and how answers to the other question could not answer yours.

Comment: @jonrsharpe partly but I've been reading lots of other examples on Meta. Yet again, another SO user who jumps to conclusions :)

Comment: @yivi That's completely my point. I've seen examples where people explain "this isn't a duplicate of... because..." but they just get ignored.

Comment: It depends. I've seen cases where the explanation is good enough to convince other voters. Reopening of questions **do** happen. Do you want to point to an example where it didn't, and where you think the closure was not appropriate?

Comment: Just because someone insists something isn't a duplicate doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. It might just mean they didn't get the solution laid out in the duplicate. In which case they should ask a *really highly focused specific question* about the exact detail that they don't get or that prevents them from applying the existing solution to theirs. Ultimately we're not here to solve *your* problem, we're here to solve *programming problems*. If we're of the opinion that a question *has* been sufficiently answered before, that's pretty much that.

Comment: @deceze and thank you for proving my point. If you scroll through the meta posts where people have argued there duplicate was not a duplicate you will see plenty of people who agree. Unfortunately, some people are same mindset as you (seemingly) and just have that itchy trigger finger over the "duplicate" button.

Comment: Well, "we" have a different point of view. "We" are writing *for future readers*, the main audience for most Stack Overflow posts. If a post isn't sufficiently distinctive from another one, they're the same for all intents and purposes for future readers. If a problem is truly not solvable by an already existing post, it should be possible to formulate a question such that this is clearly evident. Then it won't be a duplicate. It can still happen that it gets closed in error, sure, but that's something we can address on a case by base basis then and correct as needed.

Comment: TedTrippin clearly the post found by @jonrsharpe is not the one this question talks about (there is absolutely no indication of "not a duplicate of this one because x y z" nor "unusual problem that hasn't been answered before"). It may actually help your case if you provide example showing the question that started the way described in this post.

Comment: Understanding asynchrony is hard. It is even harder to debug asynchronous problems. I'm sorry but at the current state of the questions we can't help you with both of these. Please provide an MCVE (something we can run to see exactly the same output you see), explain what you think it does, then we might be able to help. But please don't blame us, we are just trying to help.

Comment: @JonasWilms hi Jonas. I'm quite adept at async prog but new to world of nodejs etc. I wasnt blaming anyone for not helping, I was ranting about how bad SO has become since more members become obsessed with simply flagging questions when they clearly havent taken the time to properly read and understand them. The question in question, I stated I had confirmed the values were set and that I was later on trying to access them - not return the values. I know I can't access a variable before its set. I guess I'll just have to learn to be crystal clear and accept there are lots of numpties :)

Answer (score 1):

It can happen that questions get closed erroneously as duplicate. After the close vote threshold was lowered from five to three votes it should happen more often now than before.

On the other hand, the usual procedure for reopening is to edit the question to explain why and how the duplicate does not apply to your question, and how answers to the other question could not answer yours. (taken from [yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393563/how-to-ask-a-non-duplicate-with-examples-and-info-without-it-being-closed-as#comment753106_393563)). Reopening also become more effective after the threshold was lowered.

It's often very helpful to ask yourself if the answers to the duplicate question answer your question. If they do not, it might not be a duplicate, but if they do it actually might be a duplicate.

If you are not sure, you can ask on meta about a specific case. [Lots of people have done so before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=not+a+duplicate+is%3Aquestion).